# Exporting environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I want to export an environment variable whose value contains a variable but I don't want that variable (which is within the value) to be evaluated during the export process. i.e.

```
export STY=for i in {0..3}; do echo $i; done
```

so my requirement is that when I echo STY, the output that I need should be

```
echo $STY
for i in {0..3}; do echo $i; done
```

But $i is evaluated during export. I need to preserve it as it is.

Comment: Are you saying that `echo $STY` should print out the actual text `for i in {0..3}; do echo $i; done`? Or are you saying that `echo $STY` should execute that for-loop? (I ask because, although it sounds to me like the former, Borealid below seems to think you really want the latter.)

Comment: Actually I want to setup the environment variable that will contain some code but will be executed in some other bash script.

Comment: How are you executing the command in the variable? Command substitution?

Comment: I am simply specifying the name of the variable like $hello

Comment: Change double quote to single quote, then try: **`eval $hello`**

Answer (score 2):

If you want what you *said* you wanted:

```
export STY="for i in {0..3}; do echo \$i; done"
```

If you want what you probably actually meant:

```
function STY() {
    for i in {0..3}; do echo $i; done
}
export -f STY
```

Comment: He could just use single quotes, i.e.


export STY='for i in {0..3}; do echo $i; done'

Comment: @Perry Six one way, half-dozen the other.

Comment: is it possible that we can execute the code contained in environment variable on command line?

Comment: By the way, if I do export such as export pqr="time ls" and if I specify this variable in some script then the code executes but if I place a for loop within this environment variable then shell yells at me and say for command not found.

Comment: @Shazard, this answer implies you use SST as function. DATA=\`STY()\` (note left quotes - they get standard output of expression). To execute non-function variable (closer to your example) use eval $STY

Answer (score 2):

Short: use eval "$hello".

(This answer originally said: use eval $hello
but another poster pointed out that eval "$hello" is safer.)

As shown below:

```
bash-2.05a$ export hello='for i in 0 1 2 3; do echo $i; done'
```

Simply saying $hello at the beginning of a line does not work - because for loops are processed before $variable expansion (phase oriented languages, I hate 'em):

```
bash-2.05a$ $hello
bash: for: command not found
```

But eval'ing works:

```
bash-2.05a$ eval $hello
0
1
2
3
bash-2.05a$
```

What you were (or might have been) doing wrong:

```
bash-2.05a$ export hello='for i in {0..4}; do echo $i; done'
bash-2.05a$ $hello
bash: for: command not found
bash-2.05a$ eval $hello
{0..4}
bash-2.05a$ for i in {0..4}; do echo $i; done
{0..4}
bash-2.05a$
```

I.e. at least in the version of bash I am using, {0..4} doesn't do what you thought it should.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/ says that the {0..4} feature came in bash 3.0+.

Perhaps you, like me (at woprk, not home), are using an obsolete version of bash?

Comment: Don't use `eval $hello`, use `eval "$hello"`.  Without the double-quotes, some unwanted parsing is done, which can cause very weird bugs.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308606/usr-bin-find-cannot-build-its-arguments-dynamically/9322047#9322047) for an example (in a rather different situation, but the same principles apply).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `$hello` doesn't run as you expected:

- Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into tokens.
- `for...do...done` is a `Compound Command` which is determined in tokenlize stage.
- `for` is not a command.

So, you cannot do this:

```
$ "for" i in {0..4}; do echo $i; done
sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

When bash split the command-line into tokens, It see `"for"` not `for`, so token `do` is unexpected.

---

In your case:

```
$ hello='for i in {0..4}; do echo $i; done'
$ $hello
sh.exe": for: command not found
```

Bash finds one token `$hello`, then `variable-expansion`&&`word-spliting` take place in order.
Actually, bash parses the result as a `Simple Command`:

- command(`for`) takes rest as args(`i`,`in`,`{0..4}`, `;`, `do`, ...)
- `for`, `do`, `;`, `done`, etc lost their special meanings.

[read more for detail](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has two sides:

- storing complex expressions in variable
- executing stored expression

To store expression, escape sequences and special quoting might be needed (that seems to be right in your example).
Execution can be performed in two ways:

- function call as in Borealid's answer: data=`STY()` - standard output of function is stored into variable
- expression evaluation: data=`eval $STY` for variable definition given in your example